# Fancyhdr: How to remove name of the subsection from header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I need help with removing the subsection name from the header. My LaTeX file names both subsection (to the left) and section (to the right) at the header, I only want the section name to be in the header. For example, looking at the picture below, I want to remove "2.1 Background" but keep the "2 Global Climate Change". A picture of my latex code is illustrated below. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\fancyhead[L]{}`?

Comment: It worked with \fancyhead[L]{} Thank you esdd :))